# What's this circular board game with dice and pegs?

Tags: identify-this-game

[image]

I have this game but don't know what it is.  My grandmother had it on the bar in her tavern/candy store around the 1920's in Baltimore.  The customers used it as a bar game to play for drinks, etc. My cousin had it in a closet for last 50 years.  None of us know what it is called or how to play it. She may have brought it over from Europe with them when they emmigrated. I have searched but cannot find any details.  Any ideas?

The game consists of:

- A circular board featuring: 24 spaces for pegs, 4 dark spaces, and 4 “pits”. Each of the spaces for pegs fits up to five pegs, and the “pits” appear to be places for storing pegs.
- A rolling space in the middle with a large number “5” printed on it.
- Seven six-sided dice.
- Approximately 70 metal pegs.

Comment: It looks like a variant of Shut the box for 4 people, your board would be between the black spots.

Comment: The dice to me look like a mix of dice that maybe came with it and ones from other places over the years.  a shut the box variant seems to make sense as 6 areas between each black division.  maybe first to score '5' in a number?

Comment: [Farkle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkle) itself was invented too late for the time period you're referencing, but it could be in the same family of games.  It uses 6 dice and would need score tracking for several people.